# Is the 3.6.2 Http Auth Backend plugin for RabbitMQ supposed to authenticate every message?

Tags: authentication, rabbitmq, mqtt

I'm using RabbitMQ 3.6.2 with the 3.6.2 version of rabbitmq-auth-backend-http. I upgraded both from 3.6.0 so that I could use the new 'post' http method for the auth backend. Previously it seemed that the service would only be called once at the beginning of an MQTT stream being published to the server. Now it seems that a request is posted to /auth/resource for every single message that's published.

Is this expected behaviour? If so, is there a way to customize the plugin to cache credentials in some way to avoid so many calls to the auth service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this plugin which looks promising, but I would accept someone else's answer if they identify a way to achieve the same result using more mature plugins or if they highlight some mis configuration on my end.

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-auth-backend-cache